# Handling javascript FormData combined with json data in an XMLHttpRequests post request received by Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, xmlhttprequest, form-data

I had some form data that I sent as json using XMLHttpRequests. This worked fine, until I needed to add some uploaded file in the post data. I did this by using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData. However, handling this data in Laravel becomes harder now. I am looking for a better solution for this. Examples:

### Sending json only

I used to send something like this:

```
const otherData = { field1: true, field2: null, field3: [1, 2, 3] };
axios.post('path/somewhere', otherData);
```

This allows me to read the request data in Laravel as simple as  `$request->field3`.

### Sending both json and a file

When a file has to be send as well, I use something like this:

```
const FormData = new FormData;
formData.append('myFile', someFile);
formData.append('otherData', JSON.stringify(otherData));
axios.post('path/somewhere', formData);
```

But now in Laravel I cannot easily access my otherData like `$request->otherData->field3`, since `$request->otherData` is just a string. I also lose other conveniences such as the TrimStrings middleware, and easy validation like `$request->validate(['field3' => 'required']);` since field3 doesn't exist anymore in the request.

Comment: add the work you have done so far

Comment: Did you try Dropzone? https://www.dropzonejs.com/

Comment: @AlexB.Santos No I didn't, but this would not make a difference. The data would still be sent to the server in the same way: "Dropzone does not provide the server side implementation of handling the files, but the way files are uploaded is identical to simple file upload forms" (https://www.dropzonejs.com/#server-side-implementation)

Answer (score 1):

So I have just solved this as I had exactly that issue - I had my lovely vue component passing JSON back to my Laravel Controller via axios and using a FormRequest to handle validation. Well, you know what happened... so the solution I used.

1) The component in the view.

```
let data = new FormData()
for (var i=0; i<this.services.length; i++){
    data.append('services[]', JSON.stringify(this.services[i]))
}
axios.post('/api/services', data, {headers: {"Content-type": "multipart/form-data"}})
          .then((response) => {
```

2) The Validation

```
class ServiceRequest extends FormRequest{

public function rules(){
   $rules = [
      'services.*.name' => 'required|min:1|max:128'  
   ];

   return $rules;
}
```

3) The bit that makes it work; override the function in FormRequest prepareForValidation like so

```
protected function prepareForValidation()
{
    $services = $this->input("services");
    $newServices = array();
    foreach ($services as $service) {
        $service = json_decode($service, true);
        $newServices[] = $service;
    }
    $this->merge([
        'services' => $newServices
    ]);
}
```

Boom! Validation works just like it did before you had the great idea to add files or images to the submission.

This works because you transform the string that is now my services array, notice in the vue component I have passed my serivces object as an array type "services[]" this was not required before using the FormData and tells PHP to convert the services[] into an array (Unique to PHP I believe). Normally that string would be automatically converted to JSON by laravel but when getting it from the multipart request is it only a string - probably because of the mime type and so need to be converted back into an object before validation, once that is done everything behaves the way it used to.